# ¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar input de un select con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `<select>` y al momento de seleccionar un valor (que en este caso seria un `value="4"`) quiero que se me active un input, sino se selecciona el 4 se deshabilita.

```html
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" name="grado_academico" id="grado_academico" onchange="">
  <option value="">Seleccionar un grado academico</option>
  <option value="1">Magisteer</option>
  <option value="2">Doctorado</option>
  <option value="3">Posdoctorado</option>
  <option value="4">Otros</option>
</select>
<input name="input1" type="text">
```

Comment: Por favor cambia el título de tu pregunta puesto lo que buscas es ocultar y mostrar no habilitar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerle un `eventListener` al `<select>` y usar la propiedad `style` en el `<input>`, usando [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para obtener ambos elementos

```js
const grado_academico = document.querySelector("#grado_academico");
const input = document.querySelector("[name=input1]");

grado_academico.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (grado_academico.value === "4") {
    input.style.display = 'initial';
  } else {
    input.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" name="grado_academico" id="grado_academico" onchange="">
  <option value="">Seleccionar un grado academico</option>
  <option value="1">Magisteer</option>
  <option value="2">Doctorado</option>
  <option value="3">Posdoctorado</option>
  <option value="4">Otros</option>
</select>
<input name="input1" type="text" Style="display:none">
```

Comment: como podria hacerlo para desaparecer el input, y al momento de seleccionar "otros" me aparezca?

Comment: Es básicamente el mismo planteamiento. En vez de usar un disabled true, le añades también a tu input un style con `display: none;` cuando sea 4.

Comment: en ese caso, el display como debe tomar el 4, ya que al aplicar display:none no se me activa el input al momento de seleccionar "otros".

Answer (score 1):

Juega con la propiedad display

```js
document.querySelector("#grado_academico").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.querySelector('input[name="input1"]').style.display = this.value == 4 ? "inline-block" : "none";
});
```

```css
input[name="input1"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Disable | enable</title>
</head>

<body>

  <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" name="grado_academico" id="grado_academico">
    <option value="">Seleccionar un grado academico</option>
    <option value="1">Magisteer</option>
    <option value="2">Doctorado</option>
    <option value="3">Posdoctorado</option>
    <option value="4">Otros</option>
  </select>
  <input name="input1" type="text">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: como podria hacerlo para desaparecer el input, y al momento de seleccionar "otros" me aparezca?

Comment: Había sido mi primer respuesta jaja. La modifiqué por eso que decía habilitar input.

Ahorita ya está para desaparecer y no; debes de jugar con la propiedad display